# EF dynamic query with enum

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to build a dynamic query whit a condition on an emum

```
enumField & enumValue == enumValue
```

for this, during the analysis the following is called

```
Expression GenerateBitWiseAnd(Expression left, Expression right) {
    return Expression.And(left, right);
}
```

this throws an exception

```
And binary operator is not defined for `EnumType` and `EnumType`.
```

The equality operator runs well

```
Expression GenerateEqual(Expression left, Expression right) {
    return Expression.Equal(left, right);
}
```

But I can't figure how to handle a [Flags] without the And bits operator.

The question is: from here how to dynamically forge my query to check my enum.

My application is targeting .Net 4

Comment: Have you tried defining the And operator yourself,  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @AntarrByrd No, but I think to and my thought is that if I do so, the linq query will not be translated to SQL by EF.

Comment: Hey! I'm facing exactly the same problem right now, that I want to check enum flags in a dynamic linq query. did you come up with a solution how to make this work yet?

Comment: @Staeff the answer seems to be just below.

Comment: @tschmit007 where do you call this function?

Comment: @Staeff I edit the dynamic.cs code found in the VS samples see [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: @tschmit007 yeah that was clear to me, but the code is a real mess and I don't see where this sould be called, I would set it somewhere in ParseAdditive() where the Ampersand Parsing is going on, but if you do this you would loose this Parsing for normal strings or?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31395/discussion-between-staeff-and-tschmit007)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to convert the `Enum` to its underlying type before you can operate on it:

```
Expression GenerateBitWiseAnd(Expression left, Expression right) 
{
   if (left.Type.IsEnum)
   {
      var enumType = left.Type;
      var compareType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType);
      var enumField = Expression.Convert(left, compareType);
      var enumValue = Expression.Convert(right, compareType);
      var and = Expression.And(enumField, enumValue);
      return Expression.Convert(and, enumType);
   }

   return Expression.And(left, right);
}
```

Comment: no more error, right now i can't check the sql because my profiler is down... but it seems to do it... big wet smack!